# Why can we write $\displaystyle u(x+h_1,y+h_2)-u(x,y)=\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}h_1+\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}h_2+|h|\psi_1(h)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

In this image, why can we write $\displaystyle u(x+h_1,y+h_2)-u(x,y)=\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}h_1+\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}h_2+|h|\psi_1(h)$ ?

[image]

[I borrowed link to the image uploaded by user119615. Thank you.]

---

I just got this idea that $u(x+h_1,y+h_2)-u(x,y)=(u(x+h_1,y+h_2)-u(x,y+h_2))+(u(x,y+h_2)-u(x,y))$.
As $u$ is differentiable with respect to $x$ and $y$, there exist functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $u(x+h_1,y+h_2)-u(x,y+h_2)=\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}h_1+f(h_1)$ and $u(x,y+h_2)-u(x,y)=\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}h_2+g(h_2)$ and $f(h_1),g(h_2)\to 0$ as $h_1,h_2 \to 0$.

I will really appreciate some comments  on this.

---

Further update: Using the mean value theorem, there exists $x<p<x+h_1$ such that
$$u(x+h_1,y+h_2)-u(x,y+h_2)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(p_1,y+h_2)h_1=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)h_1+(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(p_1,y+h_2)h_1 -\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)h_1)$$ and there exists $y<r_1<y+h_2$ such that $$u(x,y+h_2)-u(x,y)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,r_1)h_2=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)h_2+(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,r_1)h_2-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)h_2)$$
Also, $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u(x,r_1)}{\partial y},\frac{\partial u(p_1,y+h_1)}{\partial x}$ go to $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y},\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}$ respectively as $(h_1,h_2)$ goes to $0$ as the partial derivatives are continuous .

Am I headed in the right direction and if yes, how do I clean this up?

Comment: $C^1$ functions are differentiable (in the real sense), and that is exactly what those equations say.

Comment: @zhw., could you please take a look at this now?